# Django: Make the server continue to run without using runserver

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have started using django_channels on my server. But if I want the websocket to work, I have to use:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

And the server runs and I can connect `ws://myip:8080`

But, as soon as I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. It quits i.e, I am unable to connect on `ws://myip:8080` anymore.

I want to be running continuously.

Comment: the `runserver` is just for development, you should not use it in production. The answer here tells you how to run it in background but it is not correct for this. You should use something like daphne https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html

Comment: I am using gunicorn for this task now. And as @MazelTov said, the runserver command is for development. Check this link to see how to set up gunicorn https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it running in background without hanging up.
Just use below command.

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 &
```

> To kill

Find pid running on port `8080`

```
netstat -nlp | grep :8080
```

and then after you get pid

```
kill pidnumber
```

Comment: Hey, It's working. But, can you explain how does it work?

Comment: And also how to kill it, if I don't want it to run.

Comment: to kill it, `sudo ps aux | grep -i 'manage.py'`, and find the process id, and `kill -9 <process_id>`

Comment: @EricNa, I have told the same thing in my answer about running in background.